# Excel VSTO: Iterar células de acordo com as suas propriedades

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou a fazer um Add-In do Excel em Visual C# (VSTO)...

Eu queria iterar sobre as células de uma selecção (que poderá ser descontínua) que não estejam "hidden" (escondidas). Esta selecção pode ser grande.

Assim, se tiver 4000 linhas, no Excel faço os filtros (por exemplo células com ID<=100), e depois de seleccionar as linhas carrego no botão da App. (imaginemos selecciono A1:A4000, que só tem 100 linhas visíveis...).

Como é que faço isto com um `foreach`, por exemplo, ou com um `.Where` (Linq)?

Tentei o seguinte código:

```
Excel.Range selectedRange = null;

foreach (Excel.Range row in myFullRange.Rows)
{
    if (!row.Hidden)
        selectedRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Union(selectedRange, row);
}
```

mas isto não funciona: parece que `selectedRange` não pode ser `null`.

PS - Estou a usar Microsoft Interop...

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a seguinte solução:

```
            // Gets the selected range
            Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
            Excel.Range activeRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Cells;
            Excel.Range expandedRange = activeRange.EntireRow; // selects entire rows

            List<string> laddr = new List<string>();

            foreach (Excel.Range r in expandedRange.Rows) // this returns only the rows not hidden
                if (!r.Hidden)
                    laddr.Add(r.Address[true,true]);

            Excel.Range selectedRange = activeWorksheet.Range[string.Join(";", laddr)];

            selectedRange.Select();
```

Ou seja, primeiro converto o range em endereços, seleccionando os que quero, e depois converto a string em range...